# Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException

Tags: module, magento2.2

Made a simple module. But in trying to view the url I get this error.

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element >'referenceBlock', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
>   Line: 827

Looks similar to other known issues but not exactly the same. Any Ideas?

Comment: can you please add your layout.xml file?

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="cbg\ReviewReminder\Block\helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: You will notice that in this xml there is no after attribute. It must be in the core code somewhere. Just not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the 2.2.2 release. It was a core Issue.

Comment: then how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: upgrade to 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

modify your XML file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/inte‌​rnal/Magento/Framewo‌​rk/View/Layout/etc/p‌​age_configuration.xs‌​d" layout="1column"> 
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
            <block class="Cbg\ReviewReminder\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="Cbg_ReviewReminder::helloworld.phtml" /> 
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Theme layout update file 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mage22sd2/app/code/cbg/ReviewReminder/view/frontend/layout/rr_index_index.xml' is not valid.
attributes construct error
 Line: 1
Couldn't find end of Start Tag page line 1
 Line: 1
Extra content at the end of the document
 Line: 1